# Why are some of my devices in /dev/mapper symlinks while others aren't?

Tags: zfs, cryptsetup

I have the following:

```
ls -l /dev/mapper

...[snip]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        7 May 15 03:21 md1_crypt -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        7 May 15 03:21 md2_crypt -> ../dm-9
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   1 May 15 03:21 zfs1_crypt
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   2 May 15 03:21 zfs2_crypt
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   3 May 15 03:21 zfs3_crypt
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   4 May 15 03:21 zfs4_crypt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        7 May 15 03:21 zfs5_crypt -> ../dm-8
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   6 May 15 03:21 zfs6_crypt
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   5 May 15 03:21 zfs7_crypt
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   7 May 15 03:21 zfs8_crypt
```

I just created `zfs5_crypt`, `zfs6_crypt`, `zfs7_crypt`, and `zfs8_crypt`.  I used the exact same setup and configuration for all 4.

Here are the `crypttab` entries for those 4.

```
zfs5_crypt UUID=5ad31187-28b3-4636-a07e-1676e28aabdc /etc/crypt.key luks
zfs6_crypt UUID=c98d90c9-45be-4ff2-8959-f656d5c77919 /etc/crypt.key luks
zfs7_crypt UUID=96f2778b-eaf4-4cdd-841e-aca26bab96b0 /etc/crypt.key luks
zfs8_crypt UUID=49aaa246-4de7-4d62-84ed-76894f2340fe /etc/crypt.key luks
```

Why does `zfs5_crypt` show up as a symlink while the others don't.